# Checking props of a child component with shallow rendering using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, enzyme

I have a problem understanding shallow rendering of enzyme.

I have a component `WeatherApplication` which has a child component `CitySelection`.
The `CitySelection` receives a property `selectedCity` which is hold in the `WeatherApplication`s state.

The component:

```
export default class WeatherApplication extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            city : "Hamburg"
        }
    }

    selectCity(value) {
        this.setState({
            city: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CitySelection selectCity={this.selectCity.bind(this)} selectedCity={this.state.city} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I tested sussessfully that the CitySeleciton exists and that the selectedCity is "Hamburg" and the correct function is passed.

Now I want to test the behaviour of the selectCity method.

```
it("updates the temperature when the city is changed", () => {
    var wrapper = shallow(<WeatherApplication/>);
    wrapper.instance().selectCity("Bremen");

    var citySelection = wrapper.find(CitySelection);
    expect(citySelection.props().selectedCity).toEqual("Bremen");

});
```

This test fails, because the value of `citySelection.props().selectedCity` is still Hamburg.

I checked that the `render` method of `WeatherApplication` is called again and `this.state.city` has the correct value. But I cannot fetch it via the props.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling `wrapper.update()` after `selectCity()` should do the trick:

```
it("updates the temperature when the city is changed", () => {
    var wrapper = shallow(<WeatherApplication/>);
    wrapper.instance().selectCity("Bremen");
    wrapper.update(); 
    var citySelection = wrapper.find(CitySelection);
    expect(citySelection.props().selectedCity).toEqual("Bremen");    
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! 
What I don't really understand is, why I have to call it. Shouldn't the component be rerendered when the state changes (even though its shallow rendering)?

Comment: I think no. I guess if you would update state with "click" event or so, it should. PS: Great to help you!

Comment: Faced the same problem when updating state directly in jest, the child Component props(which was the parent component state) was not getting the updated value. Had to run wrapper.update()

Comment: It should be `expect(citySelection.getElements().props.selectedCity).toEqual("Bremen");` nowadays